# CSS3 Scaling box with box-shadow disappears in Safari 7

Tags: css-transitions, css, scaletransform

got a strange issue with safari 7.

I have a simple box that gets scaled on hover the funny thing since Safari 7 it seams that the box shadow disappears when scaling the box.

Does anyone else had this issue and a solution?

[image: Normal state]

---

[image: Scaled state]

Running example:
http://pizzadatoni.ch/shop/chur/pizza-xxextra/

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi Mario, I am seeing this issue as well. Just starting to investigate further, so I don't have a solution (yet). But I wanted to let you know you're not alone. I'll update with any significant findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in Webkit (as of this writing in the webkit nightly). Here's a simple [demo](http://codepen.io/sathomas/pen/FEkuz) to reproduce. And here's the [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125510) I filed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a fix, but you can avoid this problem by using filter: `drop-shadow()` instead of `box-shadow()`.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, applying a border-radius (even a small one) seems to fix the problem.

```
border-radius: 0.02px;
```

see a demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONWOGp